# React querySlectorALL not working inside react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dom

Need to get an element of the 2nd item of the array when it's clicked, but in react it won't trigger when clicking on it. In this case, we should use **querySlectorALL**, how I get this element?

```
 function App () {
  
  const List = props => {
    const listItems = props.items
    return (
      <ul>
        {listItems.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  let listItem = document.querySelectorAll('li')[1]
  if (listItem) {
    console.log('sadas')
    listItem.click()
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <List items={['A', 'B', 'C']} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: According to your example, you are programatically clicking the item before it is even rendered or created. You should use `querySelectorAll` inside a `useEffect` hook because useEffect is fired after rendering the component.

Comment: add your code  to useEffect flow when dom will be ready:
useEffect(()=>{ let listItem = document.querySelectorAll('li')[1]
  if (listItem) {
    console.log('sadas')
    listItem.click()
  },[]);